# How to disable Javascript debugging in NetBeans when using ScriptEngine?

Tags: debugging, netbeans, javascript-engine

Development environment is netbeans, java application, which runs javascript thru ScriptEngine in GraalVM.
When using debug mode, it automatically force a debug session with Chrome when scriptengine starts.

console shows: Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/xxxxxxxxxx
For help, see: https://www.graalvm.org/tools/chrome-debugger
E.g. in Chrome open: devtools://devtools/bundled/js_app.html?ws=127.0.0.1:9229/xxxxxxxxxx

But the address xxxxx  keep changing whenever I restart the debug session. I have to open chrome with the new address, because the javascript by default is paused and have to click continue in chrome for the program to continue.

Since I am not interested to debug the javascript side most of the time,  is it possible to configure netbeans to avoid this chrome debugging session started ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed when removed this `VMoption -Dpolyglot.inspect.Secure=false`